# How to transfer pdf file from the mail box to our iphone app?

Tags: iphone, email, pdf, ipad

I want to transfer a PDF received in my inbox to my application. Once I received an email with a PDF attachment and on clicking the attachment it is asking for "view it" and shows the application which supports opening PDF, after clicking the app pdf is opened in that app.In my case I have created an app which will open a pdf file. Now if I click on the pdf received in inbox it is not displaying my application for viewing.

For example if I click the pdf attachment it gives this list of app(stanza) in which pdf can be opened.I want it to list my app also, and clicking on my app I should be able to  open the pdf from my app.

Any ideas on how this could be achieved?

Comment: Why did you delete your post from yesterday that more or less asked the same question which was answered by providing a link to the section in the apple documentation that shows exactly how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, this should be the very same as on Mac OS. You need to add an `CFBundleDocumentTypes` item to your info.plist. See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-SW1) for details. This is an example:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
    <array>
      <string>ICON_FILE_NAME</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
    <string>DESCRIPTIVE NAME like PDF document</string>
    <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
    <string>Viewer</string>
    <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
    <array>
      <string>DOCUMENT_TYPE_UTI</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</array>
```

A list of all available UTIs can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009259-SW1). In your case you should use `com.adobe.pdf`. I think all that is then left is to implement the application delegate `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url` and handle the open there...

Comment: in info.plist ,when i add new information property list ,there is no option as "CFBundleDocumentTypes", should i select urltypes there and select "document icon file name" in that or something similar to it.

Comment: Just edit it by hand. You can show the file as plaintext via the context menu in Xcode. Dunno what the right name is otherwise.

Comment: what are the changes to be made, i have changed "DOCUMENT_TYPE_UTI" as "com.adobe.pdf" else kept it same.Should i change any thing else?

Comment: @Max Seelemann-->PDF gets saved under a folder inbox in documents, is there a way i can directly save it under documnets?

Comment: Don't think so. But you probably can simply move it using `NSFileManager`